# How to implement a "watchdog" service

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a service relationship that roughly looks like this:

```
{ACTIVITY} -> {SERVICE1} -> {SERVICE2}
```

The ACTIVITY starts SERVICE1 which then starts SERVICE2. It is very very important that SERVICE2 can shut itself down. If SERVICE1 crashes, SERVICE2 should have a chance to shut itself down cleanly. I've already achieved that using a remote process for SERVICE2 so if SERVICE1 crashes it can shut itself down.

The tricky part is if the user does a Force Close through the application manager.

I understand that no solution is 100%. BUT! I've noticed that the Yahoo Weather app is able to run something they're calling a "Watchdog" in a completely separate app line. Killing the main Yahoo weather app doesn't kill the Watchdog app. WHAT VOODOO IS THIS? And how can I replicate something similar?

Images of the yahoo app:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2193687/device-2014-05-22-151216.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2193687/device-2014-05-22-151236.png

Comment: I can appreciate the nearly immediate down vote, but before I get anymore down-votes, please understand that I'm not asking this lightly. I'm dealing with a very special case that interacts with janky and non-standard system services.

Comment: Thanks. I did try starting SERVICE2 in another process which solved the problem that it can shut itself down if SERVICE1 crashes, which is 90% of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm mostly curious of what Yahoo is up to with their weather app and if there's some useful design to how they are running 2 apps seperately. 

The LAST thing I want is my services running indefinitely, quite the opposite. You see, SERVICE2 actually communicates with a system process that will become unresponsive and annoy the user if they force quit SERVICE2.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Hey I didn't know the alarms were discarded after force closing the app. Is this behavior caused by that security restriction over "stopped" apps added in Honeycomb (3.1 I think)?

Comment: @MisterSmith that's the case. The process gets marked at "bad" by the system, and will not run again until the user explicitly starts it. That includes "start on reboot" as well.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier 1) The yahoo weather app is a single install from the play store. 2) Yes in the application manager I am able to stop the main "Weather" process and the watchdog process lives on. I'm running 4.4.2 on a Galaxy S4.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier No it doesn't appear to do anything. Meaning I stop the main Yahoo weather app/service, and the Yahoo weather watchdog service just keeps running, and apparently doesn't do anything (it's probably just doing something small behind the scenes). This appears to do something similar to what I want to do, I just want my watchdog to be able to run some small quick operations and then close itself if the main service gets force closed.

Comment: Aha, so the watchdog is perhaps like my watchdog. Old, outdated but still in there for old devices. In your case, I would have suggested a remote process, but you say you've already done that. I expected to see 2 processes, much like for Yahoo; so you could close the one and not the other. Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but I think I've run out of advice, sorry...

Comment: I have made an answer out of our comments, just to clean up this long list of comments... feel free to delete some of yours if you want. It will be hard to see new comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(converting conversation in the comments to an answer)

---

### Background

Typically a "watchdog service" would refer to a service running in a separate process that would try to restart some other target service if it crashes, or if the user force closes it.

Another similar trick would be to register with the `AlarmManager` to broadcast a periodic intent that would restart your app / service.

Somewhere along the way (HoneyComb I think), Android changed their security model. Apps could be marked as "bad" by the system, which would not launch them again until the user manually launched them. An app became "bad" if it crashed too often, or the user force closed it.

This includes apps that receive the `ON_BOOT_COMPLETED` intent - they will not restart if they have been marked bad like this.

So the "watchdog" stopped being as useful (some may say annoying, or battery draining) as it used to be. It might still be useful for an app that has an occasional crash

---

### Remote Process

I initially recommended a remote process as the best way to accomplish this. I then saw that you had already done this, and it works.

Unfortunately this will still not be able to restart the service if it has been stopped manually. It doesn't seem like Yahoo's WeatherServiceWatchdog is able to restart the main Weather service either.